# Local Playground installation fails to fetch sample list from npm

Tags: hyperledger-composer

On my Ubuntu 16.04 VM, I installed Hyperledger Composer Playground according to https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html.

Clicking on "Deploy new Business Network" then proceeds to load the starter templates from npm via a `http://localhost:8080/api/getSampleList` call. The response I get is:

> {"error": 
>   "code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"151.101.36.162","port":443}}

At first glance this looks like a proxy related problem, but I'm pretty sure I have my system properly configured for proxy use (so environment variables are all set, Firefox and Chrome are both configured to use our company proxy).

If I try to invoke the same http GET request via cURL (I used the "copy as cURL"-feature), I get the same response.

Digging a little further I found that `http://localhost:8080/assets/npmlist.json` lists missing dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "composer-playground",
  "version": "0.13.0",
  "problems": [
    "missing: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: cheerio@^0.22.0, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: express@^4.15.2, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: file-saver@^1.3.3, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: is-docker@^1.1.0, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: marked@^0.3.6, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: ngx-clipboard@8.0.4, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: opener@^1.4.2, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: socket.io@^1.7.3, required by composer-playground@0.13.0",
    "missing: web-animations-js@^2.2.5, required by composer-playground@0.13.0"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "composer-admin": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-client": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-common": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-connector-proxy": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-connector-web": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-playground-api": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-runtime": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "composer-runtime-web": {
      "version": "0.13.0"
    },
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": {
      "required": "1.0.0-beta.2",
      "missing": true
    },
    "cheerio": {
      "required": "^0.22.0",
      "missing": true
    },
    "express": {
      "required": "^4.15.2",
      "missing": true
    },
    "file-saver": {
      "required": "^1.3.3",
      "missing": true
    },
    "is-docker": {
      "required": "^1.1.0",
      "missing": true
    },
    "marked": {
      "required": "^0.3.6",
      "missing": true
    },
    "ngx-clipboard": {
      "required": "8.0.4",
      "missing": true
    },
    "opener": {
      "required": "^1.4.2",
      "missing": true
    },
    "socket.io": {
      "required": "^1.7.3",
      "missing": true
    },
    "web-animations-js": {
      "required": "^2.2.5",
      "missing": true
    }
  }
}
```

The following is a snippet from the logging output of the hyperledger/composer-playground docker container via docker logs "container-id" (maybe related?)

```
0|composer |request
0|composer |  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/search?text=keywords%3Acomposer-network%20maintainer%3Ahyperledger-ci
0|composer | ConnectorServer         :connectionProfileStoreLo > web-$default
0|composer | FSConnectionProfileStore:load()                   Failed to loaded connection profile web-$default {"stack":["{Error}ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/composer/.composer-connection-profiles/web-$default/connection.json' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/composer/.composer-connection-profiles/web-$default/connection.json'","    at Error (native)"]}
0|composer | ConnectorServer         :Error: Failed to load co undefined 
0|composer | ConnectorServer         :connectionProfileStoreLo < 
0|composer | info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.36.162:443
0|composer | info attempt registry request try #2 at 8:32:15 AM
0|composer | http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/search?text=keywords%3Acomposer-network%20maintainer%3Ahyperledger-ci
0|composer | info
```

Any hints how to proceed are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are behind a proxy ? VPN connection or otherwise?

If so take a look at
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/npm-behind-a-proxy-server/19386
for commands to allow npm through a proxy

Once you've resolved your proxy / connectivity issue. Suggest to do a docker cleardown of your environment and re-run the `curl` command as instructed in the doclink below and thus try the install again. Doclink -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html

Comment: I am behind a corporate proxy, yes. My npm proxy settings were there already (as described in your link). So far I've been unable to solve my proxy/connectivity problem. I have however tested to just install composer-playground via "npm install -g composer-playground" and just start it without a fabric backend. In this case, everything works fine and the starter templates are loaded correctly. So I'm more or less still confused, but on different level.